# What is the meaning when asking about the striking areas and qualities for improvement

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

I have faced a question during my application for Master program, in the section of Personal evaluation of the applicant, as: "what are the most striking qualities and areas for improvement? It's required to fill in the qualities and areas separately.

As I know, the areas for improvement should be related to Time management, Delegating, handling stress, Accuracy and so on. But, what's about field of "qualities for improvement" ? What does it should be filled in?

Comment: **Qualities** may refer to personal or corporate values, ideals, ethics, principles, team-work etc. Without knowing more of the context, it's not possible to say.

Comment: @RonaldSole the context is as I said above, It's a master application and I need to recommend him .. the section is "Personal Evaluation of the applicant". Then, the question is, what are the most striking qualities and areas for improvement? .. Two fields are required to be filled in, the first is Qualities and the second is Areas for improvement.

Comment: Then the question is asking you to examine your personal qualities and to assess which of them (honesty, generosity, ambition, diligence, flexibility, responsibility, leadership, and so on) need improvement. Ditto for what areas of your life (work, relationships, sport, volunteering.....whatever) you need to work on.

Comment: @RonaldSole you mean the areas and qualities which needs to be improved ?  It means that the applicant has weakness in those areas and qualities ?

Comment: @Fatima-Ali That's the idea. You are being asked where you can improve. It doesn't mean that you have a weakness in the areas concerned, just that further improvement is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the question as asking for the two attributes in bold.

> what are the **most striking qualities** and **areas for improvement**[emphasis added]?

The first asks for your strongest points, and the second, your weak points.

I do not see that it is asking about your "qualities for improvement", which seems unusual, as this will then be a repeat question, not to mention 'quality' is more often viewed positively.  Unless the column heading is specifically phrased that way, I believe, from what you have quoted, you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I didn't misunderstood the question, I didn't understand it at all. Could you please give me an example of answers for that question ?

Comment: Each person's most striking qualities differ from the next person's and I cannot answer on your behalf.  If, however, you are sure the heading asks for 'qualities for improvement', then the items can be what @RonaldSole listed, though I still do not see much difference between this question and that on 'areas for improvement'

Comment: I don't mean you answer on my behalf, I mean examples answers. No, I am not sure the heading asks for "qualities for improvement", I am asking about it because I didn't understand it well.

Comment: By courtesy of @RonaldSole, I copy from his list: Qualities may refer to personal or corporate values, ideals, ethics, principles, team-work etc.